# How to construct 'number block' to deal with divisibility problem？

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I am dealing with divisibility problems, such as:
Find the number of positive integers that is divisible by either of 2 or 5 within 1000. In this case, I decide to look at how many integers are divisible by 2 or 5 within 10, that is 6. So we can deduce that there are 600 numbers that could be divided by 2 or 5 within 1000.
But, what if we are trying to find number of positive integers that is divisible by both 3 or 7 within 1000, I found that the number block of '10' cannot work here, and if we try number block of '21', meaning that to find how many number is divisible by 3 or 7 within 21, and then use 1000 divides 21 to see how many blocks are there within 100, that will work. May I know what is the mechanism behind this or is there any general rule for dealing with this type problem?

Thank you so much for you guy's replies

Comment: There are $\lfloor\frac{1000}2\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{1000}3\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{1000}6\rfloor=667$ numbers between $1$ and $1000$ divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, is not divisible by 2 or 5...

Comment: @saulspatz hello sir, your method can also be used. Thank you very much. This is much help.

Comment: Sure I will change it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the number block is the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of the divisors.  If the divisors do not have a common factor it is just the product, but if your divisors are $4,6$ the minimum block would be $12$.  It is the shortest block which goes through an integer number of cycles of all the divisors.

Comment: Thank you very much sir